# Upload Android application with different version code but same version name

Tags: android, google-play, version, publish

Can I upload an application with different version code but same version name such as below:

Change

android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0"

to

android:versionCode="2"
   android:versionName="1.0"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Version Codes are unique identifiers to the different versions of your application and they must be different. Version Codes must be whole numbers too. On the other hand, Version Name is what is shown in the Google Play Store to the users and it can be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should be able to do that.

From http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html

> android:versionName — A string value that represents the release version of the application code, as it should be shown to users.

This implies that the version name is simply the string that is presented to the user.  The doc does not state that this has to be unique for each posted version of your app.  It is the *versionCode* attribute that identifies the actual version.  This is an internal integer value that is not shown to the user.